# How to setup Azure Connect?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-connect

I'm trying to setup Azure Connect so my worker role in the cloud can access my SQL Server database on my private premises.

I've followed the articles [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg445026.aspx), [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-tutorial/) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432997.aspx), but they all seem outdated.

Furthermore, i'm using Visual Studio 2012, and there is no "Virtual Network" tab on the project properties, on anything related to "Azure Connect".

I'm assuming it's been rebranded as the "Virtual Network" tab in the management portal?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Right click on the **Role** (not the cloud project) >> then **Properties** >> **Virtual Network** tab >> click on the checkbox, and paste the "Activation Token" (to be acquired using the Management Portal).

Comment: @haim770 - it's not there. As i said in the question, there is no "Virtual Network" tab. Visual Studio 2012, Azure SDK 2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Azure Connect is getting retired on July 3, 2013.  You should make the transition to Windows Azure Virtual Network before then. 
You should now use the Point-to-Site VPN feature that was announced last week (April 26): https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/

With the Point-to-Site VPN feature of Virtual Network, you can easily set up secure VPN connections between individual computers running Windows and a virtual network in Windows Azure. The feature relies on the built-in VPN client functionality of the Windows operating system (supported versions are Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2, and Windows Server 2012), so there’s no need to install an agent software, as there was with Windows Azure Connect. Furthermore, with the Point-to-Site VPN feature, you get the full functionality of the Windows Azure Virtual Network service.

Comment: I'm trying to get remote debugging to work for an Azure cloud service.  After setting up the VPN and remoting into the VM and starting the VS remote debugging monitor, VS is apparently not seeing the VPN at all.  Is there something else to do to get VS to see the remote computer?